# Cloudflare Set-up Freenom

Tags: html, github, cdn, cloudflare

I am trying to use cloudflare for my freenom .tk domain and I”m using github for hosting my website, can anyone help me set it up? I get 404
There isn't a GitHub Pages site here. on the .tk domain...

Answer (score 0):

If you have already configured your domain to use Cloudflare, the next step is to create a `CNAME` file  within the root of your repository with the name of your domain, for example:

```
your-domain.tk
```

> - (The CNAME filename must be uppercase
> - Only the bare domain or subdomain should be listed, e.g., example.com or blog.example.com, not https://example.com.

You can check more in the [GitHub troubleshooting guide](https://help.github.com/articles/troubleshooting-custom-domains/#github-repository-setup-errors):